# Salesforce lwc onclik function not running

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I have a lwc with button "Send" using onclick={sendSMS} in the html. The sendSMS function does not fire.

Here is the HTML:

```
<template>
  <template if:true={properties.showName}>
    <lightning-input
      label="Contact"
      value={params.name}
      name="name"
      onchange={valueChanged}
      disabled="true"
    ></lightning-input>
  </template>
  <lightning-input
    label="Mobile Phone"
    value={params.mobilePhone}
    name="mobilePhone"
    onchange={valueChanged}
    disabled={properties.isMobilePhoneDisabled}
  ></lightning-input>
  <lightning-input
    label="Message"
    value={params.content}
    name="content"
    onchange={valueChanged}
    disabled={properties.isContentDisabled}
  ></lightning-input>
  <div class="slds-m-top_small">
    <lightning-button
      disabled={properties.isSendDisabled}
      onclick={sendSMS}
      label="Send"
      variant="brand"
    ></lightning-button>
  </div>
  <template if:true={properties.isLoading}>
    <lightning-spinner size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
  </template>
</template>
```

Here is the js:

```
import { api, LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import sendSMS from "@salesforce/apex/SendSMSController.sendSMS";

export default class SendSms extends LightningElement {
  @api properties = {
    showName: false,
    isMobilePhoneDisabled: false,
    isContentDisabled: false,
    isSendDisabled: false,
    isLoading: false
  };

  @api params = {
    contactId: null,
    name: null,
    mobilePhone: null,
    content: null,
    correlationId: null
  };

  valueChanged(event) {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent("updatesendsmsparams", {
        detail: {
          param: event.target.name,
          value: event.target.value
        }
      })
    );
  }

  sendSMS() {
    this.properties.isLoading = true;
    sendSMS({
      mobilePhone: this.params.mobilePhone,
      contactId: this.params.contactId,
      content: this.params.content,
      correlationId: this.params.correlationId
    })
      .then(() => {
        this.showToast("Sent!", "The SMS was sent", "success");
        getRecordNotifyChange([{ recordId: this.params.contactId }]);
        this.properties.isLoading = false;
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new CustomEvent("updatesendsmsparams", {
            detail: {
              param: "content",
              value: null
            }
          })
        );
      })
      .error((error) => {
        this.showToast("Could not send SMS", error, "error");
        this.properties.isLoading = false;
      });
  }

  showToast(title, message, variant) {
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
      title: title,
      message: message,
      variant: variant
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
}
```

What is missing?

I try to press the "Send" button, but nothing happens.
I tried adding debug statements, but nothing is logged. It seems like the button is not really connected to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named your onclick sendSMS and you also imported the apex function with same local name/alias/whatever is the right terminology. Identical name, even same case ;)

What would you expect to happen? One function overwrites another? Some infinite recursion loop?

Rename the onclick-y one to something else.